# A box contains 10 apples and 10 bananas. What is the probability that each of two get 5 apples and 5 bananas?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

I was thinking that there are $\binom{10}{5} = 252$ to share apples and the same for bananas and $\binom{20}{10} = 184756$ ways to share all fruit. So $252/184756 \times 252/184756$ is sharing it all even, but I feel quite insecure. Is that even close?

Comment: Looks right to me.  Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  BTW, I didn't check the arithmetic.

Comment: "*What is the probability that each of two get 5 apples and 5 bananas*"  This is unclear.  Is it even random how the fruits are distributed?  It could be probability $1$ if we intentionally give five apples and bananas to each.  It could be probability $0$ if we intentionally give only apples to one person.  If it is random, *how specifically*?  Your approach and solution assumes that if we were to temporarily assume each fruit was distinct that the first person takes ten fruit and each subset of ten fruit was equally likely to be taken.  The problem statement mentions none of this.

Comment: Consider a completely different problem where we have two boxes and we throw the twenty fruits at the boxes, some landing in the first box, others landing in the second box, and others even possibly landing on the ground.  The first person gets whatever fruits were in the first box.  Now, its not even guaranteed that the first person gets ten fruits... they could have gotten all twenty fruit or just five fruit etc...  Still, this scenario (*although slightly absurd and still ambiguous*) satisfies your problem statement.  Please be more clear.

Comment: Now... as for what we expect the intended question was, where each person gets a uniformly selected random set of ten fruit from the twenty distinct pieces of fruit... your answer of $\left(\dfrac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{20}{10}}\right)^2$ is close but incorrect.  You effectively squared the denominator when you should not have.  It should have been $\dfrac{\binom{10}{5}\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{20}{10}}$